# What is exactly aggressive_update_packages in Anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I've recently started using the Anaconda environment and in the config list I came across an option called `aggressive_update_packages`. It is not very clear to me what happens when I add a new package to this. I couldn't find any satisfying description about this option ([only a little bit here](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/release-notes.html)), so I only can assume what it does: I think it will keep autoupdated the certain package. However I'm certainly not sure how it works, that's what I'm asking. I'm actively developing a package especially for Anaconda environment, and for others it would be a nice feature to keep it automatically updated.

Comment: _and for others it would be a nice feature to keep it automatically updated._ Wouldn't that negate some of the advantages of using virtual environments and a package manager?

Comment: @AMC It's only for a small group (not even real people, some PCs in a laboratory). Of course anyone is allowed to do that.

Comment: _It's only for a small group (not even real people, some PCs in a laboratory)._ In that case I'm not sure I understand the benefit. Can't you just have something run `conda update --all` on a schedule?

Comment: @AMC I can, but I'm just curious how `aggressive_update_packages` actually work.

Comment: https://youtu.be/zKejVMgwJuE?list=PLGB9meziqbzpoB9i8UcYMipexqdsMYutY - conda deep dive

Comment: @bigbounty That's a 30 minute long video?

Comment: @AMC Yes but it's a good video on conda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Why it exists

The default settings for the `aggressive_updates_packages` set are provided mostly for security purposes. Because Conda brings many native libraries with it, some of which provide core functionality for securely communicating on the internet, there is an implicit responsibility to ensure that it's making some effort to patch software that are frequent surfaces of generic cyberattacks.

Try searching any of the default software (e.g., `openssl`) in the [NIST's National Vulnerability Database](https://nvd.nist.gov/) and you'll quickly get a sense of why it might be crucial to keep those packages patched. Running an old SSL protocol or having an outdated list of certificate authorities leaves one generically vulnerable.

## How it works

Essentially, whenever one indicates a willingness to mutate an environment (e.g., `conda (install|update|remove)`), Conda will check for and request to install the latest versions of the packages in the set. Not much more to it than that. **It does not *autoupdate* packages**. If the user never tries to mutate the environment, the package will never be updated.

## Repurposing functionality

OP suggests using this as a way to "*keep autoupdated the certain package*". It's possible that, if your users already frequently mutate their envs, the package will get updated frequently via this setting. However, the setting is not something the package can manipulate on its own ([manipulating anything other than install files is expressly forbidden](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/link-scripts.html#adding-pre-link-post-link-and-pre-unlink-scripts)). Users would have to manually manipulate their settings to add "*the certain package*" to the list.

For users who are reproducibility-minded, I would actively discourage them from changing their global settings to add non-security-essential packages to their `aggressive_updates_packages` list.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation, I was exactly looking for this. I knew that a package itself can't manipulate the `aggressive_updates_packages`. I guess `conda update --all` on a schedule should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

According to conda release notes

> aggressive updates: Conda now supports an aggressive_update_packages configuration parameter that holds a sequence of MatchSpec strings, in addition to the pinned_packages configuration parameter. Currently, the default value contains the packages ca-certificates, certifi, and openssl. When manipulating configuration with the conda config command, use of the --system and --env flags will be especially helpful here. For example:

> conda config --add aggressive_update_packages defaults::pyopenssl --system
> would ensure that, system-wide, solves on all environments enforce using the latest version of pyopenssl from the defaults channel.

`conda config --add pinned_packages Python=2.7 --env`

> would lock all solves for the current active environment to Python versions matching 2.7.*.

According to this issue - https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7419
This might means any new env created by default adds/updates the packages in `aggressive_update_packages` configuration.

How to get the variable value? - `conda config --show`